# File I/O in Coq via ynot

Tags: io, coq

Does anyone have a small working snippet of code to **read strings from a file** in Coq (the ynot library seems to do this, but I can't figure it out)?

Ynot can be found here: http://ynot.cs.harvard.edu/
The distribution contains an IO directory in the examples, which includes `FS.v` which defines things like:

```
Fixpoint ReadFile (fm : fd_model) (ms : list mode) (fd : File fm ms) (str : string) {struct str} : Trace :=  
   match str with  
       | EmptyString => Read fd None :: nil  
       | String a b => (ReadFile fd b) ++ (Read fd (Some a) :: nil)  
   end.
```

But I can't figure out how to invoke it.

I've tried things like:

```
Eval compute in ReadFile (File (FileModel "demo.txt") [R]).  
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
Error: The term "File (FileModel "demo.txt") [R]" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type "File ?16 ?17".
```

Similarly, the Quark project (http://goto.ucsd.edu/quark/) defines `VCRIO.v` with alternative mechanisms.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

In general, you will not be able to perform file I/O directly inside Coq for the very simple reason that the underlying language Gallina is pure and total.

In particular, the function `ReadFile` you are looking at is not a function that reads a file, but a function that computes the trace generated by the action of reading a file.

The way we get around that in Quark (and its successor project Reflex http://goto.ucsd.edu/reflex ) is to axiomatize these effectful actions, see for instance https://github.com/UCSD-PL/kraken/blob/master/reflex/coq/ReflexIO.v from line 323 for the axiomatized type of our primitives.

So, on the Coq side, we reason using this monadic effectful type, and then once the code gets extracted, these axioms are realized with OCaml functions of the proper type, see here
https://github.com/UCSD-PL/kraken/blob/master/reflex/ml/primitives/ReflexImpl.ml line 111.

This obviously increases your trusted computing base, as you need to make sure your primitives do exactly what you axiomatized and no more.

---

To recap, there is no way we can execute effectful operations in Gallina itself, so we axiomatize these actions and can only really perform them with the extracted OCaml code.

I am unaware of any technique that would let you do these with rich types inside Gallina.

Comment: In fiat-crypto we have similar extraction files [for OCaml](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto/blob/master/src/StandaloneOCamlMain.v) and [for Haskell](https://github.com/mit-plv/fiat-crypto/blob/master/src/StandaloneHaskellMain.v).  There is also a [coq-reduction-effects plugin](https://github.com/coq-community/reduction-effects/) that allows printing effects during reduction, which is the output part of IO.

Answer (score 2):

Modelling IO (by axiomatizing it) and setting it up for extraction (by *realizing* it) is similar to using Haskell's FFI. You won't be able to run the code in proofs or using the interpreter though. You will only be able to run it by extracting it and compiling it. But this is just a mere inconvenience. Imagine if you defined `plus` like this:

```
Axiom plus : nat -> nat -> nat.
Infix "+" := plus.
Axiom plus_0 : forall n1, n1 + 0 = n1.
Axiom plus_S : forall n1 n2, n1 + (S n2) = S (n1 + n2).
```

This wouldn't be executable, but you would still be able to prove everything you needed to prove about `plus`. The proof terms would be larger though. For example, `eq_refl` would no longer be a proof of `2 + 2 = 4`. Also, Coq would no longer be doing any sanity checking.

For the "*realizing*" part, if you are extracting to Haskell, you do something like this:

```
Extract Constant plus => "(\ n1 n2 -> case n2 of
  O -> n1
  S n3 -> S (plus n1 n3))".
```

And then you extract it.

```
Extraction Language Haskell.
Recursive Extraction plus.
```

Now, try extracting without *realizing*.